# Using Service in the RouteServiceProvider - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to use a service I have in my route service provider.

I've tried what I normally do in any controller

```
    use App\Services\EncryptionService;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{
.. 
    public function __construct(EncryptionService $encryption) {

        $this->encryption = $encryption;
    } // end function constructor

..
}
```

the error I get is

```
ErrorException in RouteServiceProvider.php line 32:
Argument 1 passed to App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::__construct() must be an instance of App\Services\EncryptionService, instance of Illuminate\Foundation\Application given, called in /Users/Dale/Desktop/work/0.2/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php on line 7335 and defined
```

If i cant use a constructor how can I access the methods I use in the service?

Answer (score 1):

The argument passed to a Service Provider is the app itself.  You can use `App::make()` to resolve a dependency:

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{
.. 
public function __construct($app) {

    $this->encryption = $app->make('App\Services\EncryptionService');

} // end function constructor

..
}
```

You can only use dependency in a class that is resolved by the container, read on here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/container#resolving

Comment: Thanks for the reply but thats returning an error - *Call to a member function setRootControllerNamespace() on a non-object*

Comment: or *FatalErrorException in RouteServiceProvider.php line 34:
Call to a member function make() on a non-object* when using $this->app->make()

Comment: The *ServiceProvider* doesn't have a make method

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `$this->app->make()` here, you want to accept `$app` as an argument to your constructor and then call `$app->make()`

Comment: Does $app need a type before it, when I use that I get the error *FatalErrorException in compiled.php line 5590:
Call to a member function setRootControllerNamespace() on a non-object*

Answer (score 0):

This par of code looks good. The problem seems to be where you create the service for usage. So, look in your code where you do that like:

```
$myRouteServiceProvider = new RouteServiceProvider($myparameter);
```

$myparameter here must be object of type: App\Services\EncryptionService

Comment: I've never declared anything like that, i'm using the route service provider for binding variables from a URL

Comment: Ok, then look at Jeff's answer. I thought you are creating service object and then using it.

Comment: I get this error *FatalErrorException in compiled.php line 5590:
Call to a member function setRootControllerNamespace() on a non-object
*

Comment: Seems like you're trying to use object which was not created or function is not declared static if you want it to use without creating object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `boot` method.

Citation from Laravel, https://laravel.com/docs/master/providers#the-boot-method

> You are able to type-hint dependencies for your service provider's boot method. The service container will automatically inject any dependencies you need:

```
use App\Services\EncryptionService;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{
    public function boot(Router $router, EncryptionService $encryption) {
        parent::boot($router);
        //you can use your EncryptionService
    }
}
```

Comment: When using this i'm getting this error message * ErrorException in RouteServiceProvider.php line 100:
*

Comment: Hmm, you need the Router too. Changed my answer.